# Simple JavaScript Word Count Function

Tags: javascript

I finally started to learn JavaScript and for some reason I can't get this simple function to work. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
function countWords(str) {
/*Complete the function body below to count
  the number of words in str. Assume str has at
  least one word, e.g. it is not empty. Do so by
  counting the number of spaces and adding 1
  to the result*/

var count = 0;
for (int 0 = 1; i <= str.length; i++) {
   if (str.charAt(i) == " ") {
        count ++;
    }
}
return count + 1;
}
console.log(countWords("I am a short sentence"));
```

I am getting an error `SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer`

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: for loop construction should be: for (var i=0;i<=str.length;i++)

Comment: @Nile: Actually `i<str.length` so that you don't loop outside the string.

Comment: Doing a loop through each char in the string will be highly inefficient I recommend you do the following str.split(' ').length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `int` keyword in Javascript, use `var` to declare a variable. Also, `0` can't be a variable, I'm sure that you mean to declare the variable `i`. Also, you should loop from 0 to length-1 for the characters in a string:

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
```

Comment: perfect, that was it. Thanks for getting me unstuck in my Journey to learn JS

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to write this

```
for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++)
```

instead of this

```
for (int 0 = 1; i <= str.length; i++)
```

So the problems are there is nothing like `int` in javascript and also you are using `0=1` that doesn't make any sense. Just use variable `i` with `var` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
for (int 0 = 1; i <= str.length; i++)
```

should be

```
for (var i = 1; i <= str.length; i++)
```

There is no keyword `int` in javascript

Answer (score 2):

This is what you wanted:

```
function countWords(str) {
var count = 0,
i,
foo = str.length;

for (i = 0; i <= foo;i++;) {
if (str.charAt(i) == " ") {
count ++;
}

}
return console.log(count + 1);  
}


countWords("I am a short sentence");
```

btw. try to avoid declaring variables inside loop, it's faster when outside